# Embed an html web-page inside another one and scroll it using the parent scollbar

Tags: html, css, iframe, embed

I would like to have the contents of an html webpage displayed in another (parent) html webpage, stretch the embedded webpage to the width of the parent and also remove the scroll bar of the embedded webpage while being able to scroll down the contents of the embedded webpage using the the scroll bar of the main page as the height of the embedded contents are too long to fit. I tried using code from answers to similar problems including this:

```
    <iframe style='overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:100%' scrolling = "no" src="annotated list of courses.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"> </iframe>
```

but I cannot achieve the desired outcome. I would like is to be able to scroll the contents of the embedded webpage using the scrollbar of the parent page. It is possible (with no need to copy code form the embedded HTML to the parent one instead) and how? Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to resort to copying code from the embedded HTML to your page. By the way, using the example in your post, you still get only one scrollbar (the iframe's, because the parent page hasn't got one). Is that not what you need?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/mhxrk9L2/1/

Comment: There is already a scroll on the parent page in my case and I already resolved it thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by specifying a specific height for the embedded webpage which is greater than or equal to the height of the webpage like this:

```
<div id="content" class="content content-full" style="margin-top: -40px;">
    <iframe style='overflow-y:hidden; width:100%; height:17560px' src="annotated list of courses.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="17560px" type="text/html"> </iframe>
</div>
```

I hope this can solve the problem also for others and any better or different slolution is also appreciated.

ps: You have to specify a height that is at least equal to the height of the contents of the embedded webpage or element for the scrollbar to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by using two DIVs, one inside the other.

```
<div style="overflow-y: hidden; border: 2px solid black; width: 300px; height: 300px; position:absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px">
    <div style="margin-top: -100px; width: 300px; height: 400px">
        <iframe scrolling="no" style='pointer-events: none; width:100%; height: 100%' src="https://earth.nullschool.net/#current/wind/surface/level/orthographic=-325.19,32.21,3000/loc=35.073,31.923" frameborder="0" type="text/html"></iframe>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I've disabled The scrollbars by setting *scrolling="no"*
I've diasbled user clicks by setting *style='pointer-events: none;'*

Here is a working sample - https://jsfiddle.net/q46L1ynv/

Comment: Thank you! I've tried a lot of things from a lot of answers, going between object, embed and iframe. Yours was the only one that worked for me.